# Are there iterative formulas to find zeta zeros?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

I am wondering whether one could find Riemann zeta zeros iteratively by using relationships such as this one:

$$\rho _1=\lim_{s\to 1} \, \frac{\zeta (s) \zeta \left(s \cdot \rho _1\right)}{\zeta '(\rho _1)}$$

where $\rho _1 \approx 0.5 + 14.1347i$ is the first zeta zero.

Are there better relationships like Newton iteration or something like that?

The relation above that I tried to use diverges when trying to iterate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the Riemann hypothesis is true, see https://github.com/crowlogic/fastmath/raw/master/research/ZCauchy.pdf where the link is for the 4th version of the paper at http://vixra.org/abs/1702.0273  . If the there is zero of Hardy Z with nonzero imaginary part then the iteration will not reach it when started from the real line, because the complex conjugate pair would cancel their mutual influences on the trajectories of the Y iteration. If its possible to prove Im(Y_n_m) always has decreasing imaginary magnitude when started with non-zero imaginary part then that would prove that it would never converge to a zero with nonzero imaginary part because it didn't exist.

More concisely, 
Let $Y^- (t) = t - \tanh (Z (t))$ and $Y^+ (t) = t + \tanh (Z (t))$ where $Z(t)$ is the Hardy Z function, then, if the Riemann hypothesis is true then $Y^- (t)$ has attractive fixed-points at the odd-numbered zeros $Z(t_n)=0$ and repelling fixed-points at the even-numbered zeros $Z(t_n)=0$ and vice versa for $Y^+ (t)$  which would have attractive fixed-points at the even-numbered zeros and repulsive fixed-points at the odd-numbered zeros.

The multiplier $\lambda_f (\alpha)$ of a fixed point $\alpha$ of a map $f (x)$ is equal to the derivative $\dot{f} (\alpha)$ of the map evaluated at the point $\alpha$ which is the first term in the Taylor expansion at that point
\begin{equation}
  \lambda_f (\alpha) = \dot{f} (\alpha)
\end{equation}
If $| \lambda_f (\alpha) | < 1$ then $\alpha$ is a said to be an attractive
fixed-point of $f (x)$. If $| \lambda_f (\alpha) | = 1$ then $\alpha$ is an
indifferent fixed-point of $f (t)$ also known as as neutral fixed-point, and if $| \lambda_f (\alpha) > 1 |$ then $\alpha$ is a repelling fixed-pint of $f(t)$. When $| \lambda_f (\alpha) | = 0$ the fixed-point $\alpha$ is said to be superattractive fixed-point of $f (t)$.

this method only converges to simple zeros. multiple zeros of any funxtion f(t) correspond to indifferent fixed points of t-tanh(f(t)) and t+tanh(f(t)).

there is also an indifferent fixed point of Yplus and Yminus corresponding to the pole of Z at -i/2
 as well as indifferent fixed points at the trivial roots. poles of Z cause tanh to reach its limiting value at plus or minus one and the derivative of t plus or minus one is 1

The tight span, aka hyperconvex hull, or injective envelope of Y is H(t)=[t-1,t+1]

[image: Yminus(t), Yplus(t), t+1 and t-1 from t=10..30]

The homotopy of composed mappings is visualized here

[image: The homotopy of composed mappings]

[image: real and imaginary parts of the multipliers of Yplus and Yminus for a low strip of the real line from 10 to 30 as the imaginary component varies from -1/2 to 1/2]

Comment: An image similar to yours: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzwHS.png

Comment: how is your image generated?

Comment: The blue graph is the plot of the Newton-Raphson iteration applied about 7 times to the imaginary part of the Riemann zeta function +  a simple term. I don't remember where I have the code since it got deleted by the OEIS editors when I tried to enter it as a sequence there. The black dots are the Zeta zeros given automatically with the Mathematica command ZetaZero[n]. A very basic Newton-Raphson iteration anyways.

Comment: Here is the Mathematica code for the plot: https://pastebin.com/7cXWHz1m

Comment: so Newtons method applied to zeta.. you might find Kawahira's paper on the topic interesting if you haven't already read it. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06843

Comment: You can also write some code to iterate some of these functions I wrote about here.. https://github.com/crowlogic/fastmath/blob/8ce7e49cb738fefec0aa988f0d4de4f03a5314ed/src/fastmath/arb/Complex.java

Comment: That is quite a lot of code. I think that our critics agree that there are symbolic formulas for zeta zeros how ever complex. What is needed and what the critics are trying to say is that brevity is rewarded. We need either a supercomputer to check the symbolic convergenge to zero of something like: Zeta(1/2+I*formula_for_n_th_zeta_zero)=0 or if no supercomputer, we need instead a brief and fast converging formula for the n-th zeta zero so that a human mind can comprehend the convergence of the zeta function to zero. Someone said that mathematics and publishing rewards brevity.

Comment: And let me add that you also have demonstrate that the real part must be 1/2.

Comment: I think one of the problems is that if there exist any counter-examples of zeros off of the critical line that they will be far above the region which is calculable within the span of a human lifetime. Professor Ivic mentioned it would be something above the range of like 10^(10^500) or some absurdly high number. It seems that it might be possible to extend on some of the reasoning I laid out to show that the imaginary part of any iteration started off the line within the critical strip would have vanishing imaginary component. Parallel processing also cannot speed up the calculation...